Why does SetSystemTime() not set the system time?
I am trying to get my program to set the system time (Windows 10) using a GPS as a source of truth.
However, despite getting a valid time string from the GPS and converting it to SYSTEMTIME, the clock doesn't actually update. I confirmed this by setting the clock manually to some wildly incorrect time, hoping my program would then update the clock back to the correct time.
I have the following code, which I've cobbled together by looking around online:
// Enable the required privilege
HANDLE hToken;
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;
LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME, &tkp.Privileges[0].Luid);
tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, 0, (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, 0);
if (GetLastError() == NO_ERROR)
{
  // Update the system time
  SYSTEMTIME* time = &convertDateTimeToSystemTime(gpsTime);
  if (SetSystemTime(time) == NO_ERROR)
  {
    std::stringstream logStream;
    logStream << "Successfully updated system time to: " << timeString;
    std::cout << logStream.str() << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::stringstream logStream;
    logStream << "Failed to update system time, error code: " << GetLastError();
    std::cout << logStream.str() << std::endl;
  }
}
else
{
  std::stringstream logStream;
  logStream << "Failed to adjust token privileges, error code: " << GetLastError();
  std::cout << logStream.str() << std::endl;
}

And here's where I convert my time from the GPS to SYSTEMTIME:
SYSTEMTIME GpsMessageProcessor::convertDateTimeToSystemTime(const Poco::DateTime time)
  {
    SYSTEMTIME convertedTime;
    convertedTime.wYear = time.year();
    convertedTime.wMonth = time.month();
    convertedTime.wDay = time.day();
    convertedTime.wHour = time.hour();
    convertedTime.wMinute = time.minute();
    convertedTime.wSecond = time.second();
    convertedTime.wMilliseconds = time.millisecond();

    return convertedTime;
  }


The code above outputs:
Failed to update system time, error code : 1314

Which is in the else block of the if (SetSystemTime(time) != NO_ERROR) condition.

How do you set hToken?

hToken is not set anywhere, this code was found elsewhere so I'm not sure what it should be set to.

net helpmsg 1314: "A required privilege is not held by the client."

There are several problems in your code:

Your usage of GetlastError is mostly wrong. If LookupPrivilegeValue succeeds, the "last error value" used by GetlastError is not set. You need to check the return value of LookupPrivilegeValue and use GetLastError only if the return value is FALSE. Similar for AdjustTokenPrivileges, read the documentation for more details.

if (SetSystemTime(time) == NO_ERROR) is wrong, SetSystemTime, returns TRUE in case of success amd FALSE in case of failure, it does not return an error code.
It should be if (SetSystemTime(time) == TRUE) or just if (SetSystemTime(time) instead of if (SetSystemTime(time) == NO_ERROR)

hToken is not set anywhere, AdjustTokenPrivileges needs a valid token handle, you forgot this: if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken)) ...


Also don't forget to close the handle by calling eventually CloseHandle(hToken).
So basically you want something similar to this:
void DisplayError(DWORD errorcode, const std::string message)
{
    std::cout << message ": error code:" << errorcode << "\n";
    exit(1);
}

...
// Enable the required privilege

TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;
if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME, &tkp.Privileges[0].Luid))
{
    DisplayError(GetLastError(), "LookupPrivilegeValue");
    exit(1);
}

HANDLE hToken;
if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken))
{
    DisplayError(GetLastError(), "OpenProcessToken");
    exit(1);
}

tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, 0, (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, 0))
{
    DisplayError(GetLastError(), "AdjustTokenPrivileges");
    exit(1);
}

// Update the system time

// the rest of your time setting stuff goes here


One more thing: this is fishy, as it is passing a dangling pointer to SetSystemTime() which is undefined behavior:
SYSTEMTIME* time = &convertDateTimeToSystemTime(gpsTime);
SetSystemTime(time)

It should be:
SYSTEMTIME time = convertDateTimeToSystemTime(gpsTime);
SetSystemTime(&time)


Thank you for the suggestions, I've made the suggestions that you recommended but I still get error code 1314. Is there some Windows security setting that needs to be enabled? The program is being run by admin.

@EraticMagician Where exactly do you get this error code? Update your question with your new code (with all of my suggestions),  add some more cout << "whatever";, so we know exactly what your program did and show the verbatim output.

While your DisplayError() helper function provides a useful and necessary guarantee that GetLastError() is called before performing I/O, you lost the variation in the string which is quite important.  In the original question, the output "Failed to update system time, error code : 1314" tells you exactly where the error code came from.

@BenVoigt good point. I updated the answer.

@Jabberwocky "this is fishy" - that part of the code shouldn't have even compiled in the first place, as C++ doesn't allow taking the address of a temporary object.

Also, your "same for AdjustTokenPrivileges" comment about conditioning GetLastError() on a failure return value is incorrect.  The documentation indicates to call GetLastError() on success to check for ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED.

@RemyLebeau • /permissive as a default (C++17 and earlier) probably allowed it.
